# pytorch model predicts fixed label when it exports to onnx

Tags: opencv, pytorch, onnx

I trained resnet-18 model in pytorch. And it works well in pytorch.
But, when I converts it to onnx and predicts in cv2, model predicts only 1~2 label(it should predict 0~17 labels).
this is my model export code

```
    model.eval()
    x = torch.randn(1, 3, 512, 384, requires_grad=True)

    # export model
    torch.onnx.export(model, x, "model.onnx", export_params=True, opset_version=10, do_constant_folding=True, input_names = ['input'], output_names = ['output'])
```

And this is my code for inference in cv2

```
self.transform = albumentations.Compose([
        albumentations.Resize(512, 384, cv2.INTER_LINEAR),
        albumentations.GaussianBlur(3, sigma_limit=(0.1, 2)),
        albumentations.Normalize(mean=(0.5), std=(0.2)),
        albumentations.ToFloat(max_value=255)
        ])
...
#image crop code: works fine in pytorch
image = frame[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]  #type(frame)==numpy.array, RGB form
augmented = self.transform(image=image)
image = augmented["image"]
...
#inference code: does not work well
net=cv2.dnn.readNet("Model.onnx")
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, swapRB=False, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
label = np.array(net.forward())
text  =  'Label: '+str(np.argmax(label[0]))
```

All transform settings works well in pytorch.
What can be the problem in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code probably has to do with preprocessing the images differently: `self.transform` rescales the image, but when you are reading `blob`, you are not doing that. To verify this, you can read the same image and check if the `image` and `blob` are equal (e.g. using `torch.allclose`), when the actual (random) augmentations are disabled.

Comment: Actually, I do apply same argumentation to both blob and image. but somehow blob and image does not match in torch.isclose. 
thank you for your help